# Android Firebase phone auth didn't send any sms

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm following the code from [quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth) but didn't receive any sms.

My Project id is : pa2017-b83b3

My Country is : Indonesia, that included in this [list](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#develop)

My phone number that tested is : +6282234642914

The log said :

```
onCodeSent: [some key]
```

But I didn't receive anything..

Update :
I also trying using FirebaseUI-WEB demo [here](https://fir-ui-demo-84a6c.firebaseapp.com/), and didn't receive any sms either.

Compare to this, Facebook account kit is always succeed within seconds.. and more free quota. But i'm a firebase fans.. so please fix this.. thx

Comment: Hey @faruk, can you file an issue with Firebase support? They will need the approximate time-stamp of the messages to investigate the reason behind this. Keep in mind, this feature has just launched worldwide (a couple of weeks). It is a fairly new product which requires partnership with carriers all around the world. Please report this issue so they can help fix it so others don't encounter it.

Comment: @bojeil the time milis of the last try is between 1497290022853 and 1497290119693 from the https://currentmillis.com/

Comment: I contacted the Firebase support team regarding your case. They have sent below messages to +6282234642914, can you confirm you got either messages. It is possible that the existing messages are getting blocked due to certain keywords. This will help determine this.
1) content: "Test message from SMS-Ops." sent at 20:35:30 Pacific Time
2) content: "123456 is your verification code." sent at 20:39 Pacific Time

Comment: @bojeil First message is sent, but second message is not

Comment: Very helpful. I think some key words are causing the message to be blocked. will relay this.

Comment: @bojeil  
I've already try it my self. You were right, this stupid carrier blocked any sms that contains "your verification code" could you change the sms format like twitter digits, with something like "Enter code: xxxxxx"

Comment: Does "Enter code: xxxxxx" work? If so, I will relay that to the support team.

Comment: @bojeil yes "Enter code: xxxxxx" will work, or "your code is xxxxxx" is also work, but strangely "your verification code somechar" is failed on sending sms. I've already complain to the call center, but they just ignore me and think that i'm crazy..

Comment: @faruk First message is sent, but second message is not - Same thing happening to me. any possible solution? i don't think its related to SMS content. Bcz if that was the issue then i wouldn't be getting the SMS for the first time as well.

Comment: Hey @faruk, can you try again, the fix should be in production (using customized message without blocked words) for Indonesia.

Comment: @bojeil thank you very much.. it works very well now..

Comment: @bojeil i'm sorry.. Unfortunately there is still 2 operator remain that failed to get sms, I've already reply to firebase support

Comment: Hey @faruk, can you try one more time? it should send a message of the form: Enter: 123456, App: appName

Comment: @bojeil there is still one carrier that didn't receive sms. This carrier has two child carrier first is XL and second is Axis, The XL one (+6281703660176) is receiving sms, but the Axis one is still not, sample (+6283831120642).

Comment: Hey @faruk, can you try to test the remaining carrier, what message with a code would be allowed without getting blocked? there is little left to remove in that template.

Comment: @bojeil It succed now.. thank you very much for the great support from firebase team

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am glad it works now.

Comment: Got my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/1713519