# "This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am making a app that requires firebase authentication and i am receiving a error.

"This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.

- sha-1 is correct
- Project package is correct
- Project is connected to firebase
- dependencies are setup properly
- Phone auth is enabled

One thing more i only receive this error when i download the app from playstore else when i install it from android studio the app works fine..

Comment: I guess your problem is that you have to add 3 sha1 keys in order to work.
I had a similar problem, checkout me post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360250/firebase-ui-authentication-with-google-fails-with-message-code10-message10

Comment: I have got a very simple trick to resolve it, Check my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63497472/5639557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After releasing the app, the play console generate new certificate which is called "App signing certificate". It contains the SHA1 certificate that you require. It can be found at:

Released Management->App Sigining on your play console. Copy it and paste it in your firebase app -> project settings -> add sha1 fingerprint.

Comment: Can u explain in more details about this. I am not able to understand Released Management->App. Where can I find this option