# Firebase Phone Auth isn't sending the sms

Tags: android, firebase, sms

I don't know what to do, App was working well and performing sms verification few hours ago, I just came back but the same didn't work. Now it's not even sending the sms because resend token is null,

```
@Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            Utility.log("onCodeSent: " + verificationId);
            Utility.log("token: " + token);
            pbVerify.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;

        }
```

This method is not calling since because mResendToken is null, I have checked permission those are ok. It was working perfect 8 hours ago.

Comment: Have you enabled it as an authentication on the dashboard?

Comment: yes, of course it was working perfect since last 10 days, but suddenly it stopped working

Comment: Did you found any solution, I am also having same case?

Comment: @Nainal waiting for sometime will resolve the issue. As sending too many verification sms are not encouraged. You may get these sms on number after delay

Comment: Got my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/1713519

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Firebase restrict certain numbers for excessive login usage. You can go to Authentication >> Sign-In Method >> Select " Phone " >> Then add the number you are using for testing with a "default code" which you will use as the verification code during your sign in authentication. After adding your number and default code click on Save, and after that you can easily test authentication from your number.

Below are some screenshots to help you how to add your number for testing Firebase Authentication.

[procedure to add your number for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/803aY.jpg)

[example of how to add your number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inmLB.jpg)

Comment: I have done that, but the issue is sms is not going to any number

Comment: should I provide you GitHub link?