# Phone verification otp message not receiving in singed apk only working in debug apk

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I integrated Firebase mobile verification in my Android app, but it's only working in the debug APK; and not in the release apk (otp not receiving in release version)

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

Also, I generated SHA1 and pasted in Firebase config, and my `google-service.json` is the latest one.

Comment: Please make sure that your release keystore SHA-1 is on firebase and after that you are using latest google-service.json

Comment: yes, SHA-1 is there in firebase

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/2289835) answer.

- Get SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from Developer console and put it
  in Firebase.

[image]

Comment: it is not working in my phone POCO F1 Android 9 , in other phones its working,(debug version working)

Comment: @Muhsin, Is it working in **other phones** with **releases-version??**

Comment: Then it can be problem of device-dependency. It's not problem with **Signed apk.**