# Android Phone Number Verification in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a login screen which will use Phone Number Authentication in Firebase. I wrote a code;

```
package com.example.logindeneme;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PhoneLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button SendVerificationButton, VerifyButton;
    private EditText InputPhoneNumber, InputVerificationCode;

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks callbacks;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    private String mVerificationId;
    private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();;

        SendVerificationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_ver_code_button);
        VerifyButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.verify_button);
        InputPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number_input);
        InputVerificationCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.verification_code_input);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);


        SendVerificationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String phoneNumber = InputPhoneNumber.getText().toString();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)){
                    Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Please enter your phone number first...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    loadingBar.setTitle("Phone Verification");
                    loadingBar.setMessage("please wait, while we are authenticating your phone...");
                    loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    loadingBar.show();
                    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
                            60,                 // Timeout duration
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
                            PhoneLoginActivity.this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
                            callbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                }
            }
        });

        VerifyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SendVerificationButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                InputPhoneNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                String verificationCode = InputVerificationCode.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(verificationCode)){
                    Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Please write verification code first...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    loadingBar.setTitle("Verification Code");
                    loadingBar.setMessage("please wait, while we are verifying verification code...");
                    loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    loadingBar.show();

                    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, verificationCode);
                    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
                }
            }
        });

        callbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
            }

            @Override
            public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                loadingBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Invalid Phone Number, Please enter correct phone number with your country code...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                SendVerificationButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                InputPhoneNumber.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                VerifyButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                InputVerificationCode.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                                   PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {

                // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
                mVerificationId = verificationId;
                mResendToken = token;

                loadingBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Code has been sent, please check and verify.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                SendVerificationButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                InputPhoneNumber.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                VerifyButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                InputVerificationCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };
    }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Congratulations, you're logged in successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            SendUserToMainActivity();
                        }
                        else {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(PhoneLoginActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }
                });
    }

    private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(PhoneLoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

But when I try to enter my phone number and want a code, always says "Invalid phone number". However, if I enter my number and random verify code in Test Phone Numbers in Firebase, and if I enter in my app; it works.

My country uses "+90" phone code. So I tried +9053XXXXXXXX, +90 53X XXX XX XX, +90-53X-XXX-XX-XX and etc. but never works.

Where is my fault? Can you fix it ?

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly if the SDK isn't working as you expect.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: @DougStevenson I wrote a report to them, thank you. But do you think that problem is from Firebase crew?

Comment: check out tutorial for verify your code   https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-phone-authentication-android-tutorial/

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53428463/2289835) and [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53919884/2289835)

Comment: @Mohsinkazi @RumitPatel I tried your suggested tutorials but I received the same error in all applications you suggested. Error is ; `This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify the corecct packgage name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [App validation failed]` but I followed tutorials about get sha1 and I have same sha1 as I have in Firebase

Comment: @Wicaledon I want to know which apk you are use debug or signed . or check solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46751810/10758304

Answer (score 0):

@Wicaledon 
Go to your firebase console.

In Settings, enter your add your SHA-1 key.

This will definitely work.

To get SHA-1 key
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth