# This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have used FirebaseUI Auth to authenticate , Auth via email is working any other auth is not working .
I have Enabled Auth options in Firebase

I have seen this [This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751766/this-app-is-not-authorized-to-use-firebase-authentication-please-verify-that-the/46751810)
but it didn't solves the problem
Errors:

```
   E/Volley: [1404] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/sendVerificationCode?alt=proto&key=
2019-07-27 21:12:28.262 2809-11221/? W/FirebaseAuth: [PhoneVerificationSession] onFailure
2019-07-27 21:12:28.283 12142-12142/? E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed ]
```

Synced with Firebase tried manually even
by both SHA1,SHA256 
I have not uploaded to Play Store

I am in this doubt from almost one weeks and seached eveywhere , so i noted them all, Any Solution

Comment: did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using React native use the `debug.keystore` which is inside `yourRNproject/android/app` to generate the SHA1 put it in the firebase console, download the `google-services.json` in your project and there you go.