# This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication on USB Debugging

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have done exactly what this question's answer says: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/10021456

I copied both my ***App signing certificate SHA-1*** and my ***Upload certificate SHA-1*** to my ***Firebase SHA certificate fingerprints***

I am just trying to run a Flutter app on my mobile phone, through USB debugging. So it is not a download from the app store or anything. Right at the start I get this error when I try to create a new user using ***Phone Number Authentication***

Any idea on what I might be missing?

(I use ***Flutter*** for my app)

**Information:**

Example phone numbers work fine. But normal/unregistered phone numbers give the error.

This is the error message:

> This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.Please
>   verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the
>   Firebase Console

Comment: What is the error message and have you tried with example phone numbers? (these can be configured on firebase console)

Comment: Did you also added debug keystore sha1 to firebase? App signing certificate sounds like the release keystore

Comment: @ChennaReddy I updated my question with the details you asked for

Comment: @xSHERU I don't understand what you mean with `Did you also added debug keystore sha1 to firebase?`. Where do I get a debug key?

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: @xSHERU VSCode :)

Comment: I think the directory I shared is same @PaulKruger i will confirm it once i reach home this evening. Meanwhile check if I am correct

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you. I don't know about the windows. But this solution for Linux users.

Go to Project folder `cd android`
then open the terminal ( Ctrl + Alt + T )

Run this comment  `./gradlew signingReport`

You will get the SHA1 and SHA256  for your project. Copy that SHA1 and SHA256, Paste it in Google firebase.

That's worked for me. If you face any problem contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey based on our conversation, probably you haven’t added debug keystore SHA-1 to firebase console app configuration.

If you are using Android Studio on Windows then it will be located at

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.android\debug.keystore
```

In case you are using Android Studio on Mac then it will be located at

```
/Users/USERNAME/.android/debug.keystore
```

In case you don’t find the file in said directory then just use android studio to install app on your phone. It will be generated automatically.

As you have already added release keystore SHA-1, I think you know how to get SHA-1 from keystore. You can also use Keystore Explorer tool for it.

UPDATE 1:
Since you are using android studio now to build your app it became easy.

1. In android studio on right hand side you will see Gradle Tab. Open it.
2. Open (root) in this tab.
3. Open Tasks -> android
4. Click on ‘signingReport’
5. You will find the signing report at the bottom and scroll through it you will see SHA1 just copy it to your firebase project settings.

Hope this will solve your issue.

UPDATE 2:
You can get SHA1 of that keystore by other means as well.

Download this tool and open your debug keystore file using this application.
Get the SHA1 from there and add it to your Firebase Configuration.
http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html

Comment: I tried building the app with android studio, that doesn't work. I do have a debug.keystore file on my mac at that location, but what do I do with it?

Comment: I don't see a gradle tab, would you have this in a Flutter app?

Comment: @PaulKruger use the tool I have added.