# simpliest android app firebase authentification via google without e-mail

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, authorization, firebase-security

my intention is to create good rule for Firebase and friend it with my app, I started with simple one - user is authorized:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

what was done to auth my app via google+Firebase:

1. generated keystore file
2. keystore file usage is configured in graddle so that app is signed by it
3. [SHA1 is added to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751766/this-app-is-not-authorized-to-use-firebase-authentication-please-verify-that-the)
4. new google-services.json is downloded in app folder
5. [instruction](https://androidwave.com/google-sign-in-using-firebase-android/) followed to auth application via google ([and official one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin))

somehow application is going to be authorized via e-mail like:

```
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        // for the requestIdToken, this is in the values.xml file that
        // is generated from your google-services.json 
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build();
```

I believe that this .requestEmail() opens auth form in my app UI with request to enter e-mail (line comment doesn't help)...

the points are:

1. my application is signed via keystore, and Firebase + google know that
2. I don't need user to authorize or enter any e-mail
3. all I need is to have my app automatically authorized for Firebase (don't care about google, but prefer usage of keystore + SHA1) so that Firebase rule will work (and later replaced with my true app uid)

What's the best/easiest approach to authorize app for Firebase and filter access in DB rule? (without any e-mail entering)

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication with Google, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Comment: thank you! but it again looks like work with e-mail and needed authorization by user, which I want to be auto

Comment: yeah, looks pretty much the same as official docs, it requests user to enter e-mail+password, which I don't want. I need a solution how to authorize my application in the background without entering any e-mail

Comment: You may find assistance for advice here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact