# firebase Phone authentication is not working in release version

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I used firebase Phone authentication is not working, It worked in debug mode but when I released it on playstore in release version it shows flowing error

*Varification failed
com.google.firebase.authFirebaseAuthException:
This app is not authorised to use Firebase authentication.Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [App Validation Failed]*

[This is the screenshot of the error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Pop.jpg)

Comment: Please do web searches for error messages before posting to Stack Overflow.  What you encountered here is a very common.  If you've already tried some things to solve this, your question should contain everything you tried.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio:

[image]

Click Gradle>Tasks>android>signingReport and copy SHA1 key.

Then go to Firebase console, click your project > Project settings.

Paste your key into the dijital fingerprint section below and add.

**Edit:**

Also you can have a look this post.[This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751766/this-app-is-not-authorized-to-use-firebase-authentication-please-verify-that-the)