# Firebase Authentication doesn't work after publishing the app in Open Testing Mode

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Phone Authentication in my app and everything worked fine before I published the app on Play Store. After the publication in **Open Testing Mode**, users can not authenticate with their phone numbers anymore. I have already included the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from Play Store console (located in App Integrity) in my Firebase console but it still doesn't work. Is there anything that I should do which I haven't done?

Please note that I have enabled Google Play App Signing, and I uploaded my Android App Bundle (.aab) on Play Store.

Comment: please add your sha kye into google play store than its will start working

Comment: @Amitpandey Do you mean Firebase console? I have already done it as I mentioned in my question. is it even possible to manually add a SH-1 fingerprint in play console?

Comment: You can have a  [look at this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/2289835)

Comment: @RumitPatel Thank you for the reference. I have already done this but still no luck.

Comment: There us 2 type of SH-1 one is realse and the other is debug please add relase SH-1 into firebase and google play consol

Comment: @Amitpandey Yes, I do understand this and I am only using release SH-1 fingerprints. I have already added these two fingerprints in firebase console. Would you elaborate more on what you mean by adding this to play console?

Comment: see this link you have to add your SH-1 into your google play consol as well to get the phone authentication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751766/this-app-is-not-authorized-to-use-firebase-authentication-please-verify-that-the/53513327#53513327

Comment: @Amitpandey I have already done this. but the problem is not solved. Please read my question one more time.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot and implementing different solutions, I fixed the problem by enabling **Android Device Verification API** in google developers console. Only adding SHA-1 fingerprints was not enough in my case.