# Firebase deploy - Cannot publish a model that is not verified

Tags: python, firebase, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, firebase-machine-learning

I'm trying to deploy a `.tflite` to Firebase ML so that I can distribute it from there.

I used transfer learning on [this TF Hub model](https://tfhub.dev/google/bit/s-r50x1/1). I then followed [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert) to convert the model `.tflite` format.

This model gives good results in the python TFLite interpreter and can be used on Android if I package with the app.

However I want to serve the model via Firebase, so I use [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml/manage-hosted-models) to deploy the `.tflite` file to Firebase. Using this tutorial, I get an error `firebase_admin.exceptions.FailedPreconditionError: Cannot publish a model that is not verified.`.

I can't find any information about this error anywhere, and given the model works on both Android and Python, I'm at a loss as to what could be causing this

Comment: Did you try the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66650294/13546426)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this issue? I had the same one, and it turned out the model size  should be < 40mb. That caused the error, and the detailed error is only reported when uploading a model manually through web Firebase dashboard

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer