# unknown status code: 17028 A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered

Tags: firebase, flutter, verification, one-time-password

unknown status code: 17028 A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered in the Firebase console. Please make sure that this application’s packageName/SHA256 pair is registered in the Firebase Console.

hello there, i m facing this issues while developing application, i have tried to fix and these are the steps i have done so far but the same result:

- correctly configured the firebase and my flutter application by using the steps on firebase
- i have signed my app and added the signing key both debug and release keys, both SHA-1 key and SHA-256 key
- I have enabled Android Verification in google cloud page also
- i have enabled the authentication provider, phone authentication enabled, password/email enabled

in addition to that when i use testing phone number i added to the console and the otp code i insert, my app works perfectly
but when trying to authenticate the phone using  other un registered phone numbers it keeps showing me error.

i have cheched flutter doctor -v it has no error
also execute flutter commands there is nothing error related thing on the result. I have used the following firebase plugins

firebase_auth: ^0.18.4+1
firebase_core: ^0.5.3
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.4
firebase_admob:
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
firebase_storage: ^5.2.0

any help from you would be appreciated

Comment: can you please add the error from the console ?

Answer (score 6):

The solution to this is:
If you did your configuration of firebase and app project correctly then

- Run `flutter clean` to clean your project dependencies.
- Download new google-services.json file from firebase and add it to app folder in flutter project.
- Run `flutter pub get` to get all dependencies again.
- Run your project.

Then you're good to go. It worked for me.

Comment: All these steps tried.

Comment: So, it worked or not?

Comment: Still i am facing the same issue, still investigating

Comment: The solution to this is:

Press 'Win + R' and run "resmon.exe".
Go to CPU tab and search for "build" in Associated Handles search bar.
Right click on "java.exe" process and click on END PROCESS.
Run flutter clean to clean your project dependencies.
Download new google-services.json file from firebase and add it to app folder in flutter project.
Run pub get to get all dependencies again.
Run your project.
Then you're good to go. It worked for me.

Comment: I am using ubuntu, can you detail about what to do on ubuntu ?

Comment: bro haven't worked on ubuntu on flutter yet. what you can do is google how to kill java.exe process in ubuntu and I think you would be good to go. rest of the steps might be the same. For your reference I am attaching the link:
https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+kill+java+exe+process+in+ubuntu&oq=how+to+kill+java.exe+process+in+ub&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j33i22i29i30.16634j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: just needed to rebuild the project , thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

If all above solution tried, follow my solution. I believe your problem may be same as mine.

please check your `android/app/build.gradle` file.

```
signingConfigs {
        if (System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH")) {
            release {
                storeFile file(System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH"))
                keyAlias System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS")
                keyPassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD")
                storePassword System.getenv("ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            }
        } else {
            release {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }
    }
```

In my verygood cli created project signingConfigs is configured for only release build, so my own generated key is not using for build debug apk. So

From root directory of flutter project

```
cd android/
./gradlew signingReport
```

Collect your default SHA-1 and SHA-256 key and updated on firebase console.

`flutter clean` and run project

Don't need to update `google-service.json` file

Comment: This part solved it:
From root directory of flutter project

    cd android/
    ./gradlew signingReport
Collect your default SHA-1 and SHA-256 key and updated on firebase console.

Answer (score 3):

Im my case i found out that google has put my app i guess in blacklist, cos i have tried the same code with different app key, it worked as a charm, but that key has been blacklisted that it doesn't work still.

thanks for your answers, surely appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar problem. My solution was: Regenerate my-upload-key.keystore. I hope it will be useful!

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable app verification.

You can check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/14709655

and you can use this link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

In my case my SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys that are added in firebase were different with play store app integrity certificates.

So I added both in firebase project setting one from local machine and another from play console app integrity as shown in picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I face a similar problem.  So Please Add SHA-256 Key On Firebase Not SHA-1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, while testing the Phone OTP Authentication
E/FirebaseAuth( 6429): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17028 Invalid app info in play_integrity_token

After checking all the configuration, SHA1, SHA256, googleservice.json,build file.

I solved it by,

Adding the Phone Number for Testing: In the Firebase console, navigate to the Authentication section -- Signin method -  press the Edit button in the enabled Phone and find the "Phone numbers for testing" option down. Add the phone number you want to use for testing.

And test with the given phone number and OTP.

When you specify a phone number for testing in the Firebase console, Firebase allows authentication using only those specified numbers for testing purposes. Any other phone numbers used for testing will result in error code 17028, indicating that the operation was denied due to security rules