# Firebase phone auth not woking for application build from Circle Ci

Tags: firebase, android-studio, circleci

I have been working on automating a build process. Everything is working fine if I switched off my Firebase plugins in my grade. But if I open a Firebase plugin and make a build through automation then my application doesn't allow me to log in. It starts throwing an error as follows

"**This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console**"

I have added SHA-1 and SHA-256 FingurePrint to the Firebase console of my server where applications get built using Circle CI.

But if I make a build on my local machine and put SHA-1 and SHA-256 of my Android studio the application allows me to get logged in.

Please guide me that how I can make my build work with Circle CI and what SHA-1 and SHA-256 should be uploaded on the Firebase console to make my auto-generated build work.

Please let me know if you need any more information to help investigate my issue.

Comment: Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I am stuck on this from the past 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout these answers

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46751810/5580690
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62362112/5580690
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/5580690

[Circle CI Google Auth](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/google-auth/)

[Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/continuous)