# Firebase Auth (phone number verification

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I wanted to use Firebase for authenticating with phone number, but i get this error

**This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console**

But everything is perfect to go. I couldn't paste a code snippet because there's nothing to change. What can i do?

I've tried so many ways, even i recreated Firebase projects.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751766/this-app-is-not-authorized-to-use-firebase-authentication-please-verify-that-the)