Flutter Firebase phone auth not working for android
I'm currently distressed now. For weeks I've been trying to get my Android app to get the Firebase phone auth to work but doesn't work.
I have my SHA-1 and SHA-256 all set in my Firebase console

I also have my Play Integrity registered in the Firebase console.

But after all these, my phone auth is still not working.
It gives me the following errors.

This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console.

The phone auth works well on my IOS simulator and IOS real device, but I don't know what's wrong with my android.
Please help

Does your app package name match the one registered on Firebase?

I don't really understand. I configured my Firebase project with the Firebase config method. Unless you are talking about something else, then no

Could you please elaborate on that

Check this answer, with so little information there is nothing specific to tell you, but you might see what you need here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/11891580
