firebase flutter phone authentication issue
I'm creating a flutter app using firebase for backend everything is working great in development and release mode testing but when I deploy the app to play store and try to login or signup through mobile number it shows the error

an error has occurred, please try again. this app is not authorized to use firebase authentication. please verify that the correct package name, sha-1, and sha-256 are configured in the firebase console. [ a play_integrity_token was passed, but no matching sha-256 was registered in the firebase console. please make sure that this application's packagename/sha256 pair is registered in the firebase console. ]

I added all the SHA-1 and SHA-256 in the firebase also added latest Json file in the project but nothing works




I did Firebase phone authentication many times before but this time I don't know what's the issue/bug.

also my package name in the firebase and on the play store are the same.

I remember running into this a while back. Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513327/9824103

@sleepystar96 thanks for your precious time and answer. I already know this that's why I added images so everybody can check it.

I did everything but IDK why it's not working.

One thing you can try is go to Firebase console -> Project Settings -> Integration and connect your Google Play store app with Firebase.
