# Firebase phoneauth SMS are sometimes not beeing sent with no error message (iOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, ionic3

**Ionic 3 App**

I have been using this plugin: *cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5* with no problems for almost a year now, all phoneauth tests worked fined for both iOS and Android. A week ago the production version (in stores) started having downloads and user registrations and we noticed that some of the user never recieved the SMS while others did recieve it with no problem. I tested it myself and found this behavior where sometimes I recieved it and sometimes I didn't, even if tried different phone numbers or devicec (tried on 4 different android diveces and on 2 iOS).

There is no error catched on the "verifyPhoneNumber" function (just when I tried for too many times and I exceed the 10 sms per hour per user cuota).

I contacted the firebase support team and they told me that don't have reports of any incidents on their status dashboard and could not offer any more help since this is not their official SDK.

I have further the research on why this could be happening, and I strongly believe that it could be due to phone carriers (from Mexico) blocking the messages with certain contents as commented in this issues by @bojeil:

[Android Firebase phone auth didn't send any sms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490768/android-firebase-phone-auth-didnt-send-any-sms)
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/287

**Expected behavior**
SMS should be sent with any problem all the time.

I have 2 proyects in firebase for this app (production and development) and with both I have experience this same behaviour. I dont think the problem is in my code but put it to further the information:

```
this.firebaseNative.verifyPhoneNumber(this.telephone.full, 120).then(res => {
    this.verificationId = res.verificationId; // android case, on iOS I get 
    the string directly from the response // ... promt the user to input the sms code 
}).catch(
    error => { console.error(error); // ... });
```

The question is: ¿How could I know if the messages are being blocked, and how could this be solved?